# Get EXIF data of a particular image/photo in cameraroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, camera-roll

I am using ALAssetsLibrary to list details of photos present in cameraroll. But how to get details of a particular selected photo from cameraroll using **ALAssetsLibrary**?

Assume i selected ABC.jpeg from cameraroll. I want to display the exif details of only ABC.jpeg. Not exif details of other photos present in cameraroll.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
   self.imageView.image = image;

   NSLog(@"image %@\ninfo: %@",image, info);
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (group) {
            [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
                if (asset){

                    NSDictionary *data = [[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata];
                    NSLog(@"%@",data);
                }
            }];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
    }];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get exif information from ALAsset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475057/how-to-get-exif-information-from-alasset)

Comment: @Daij-Djan How can i get exifinformation of randomly selected photo from cameraroll. I don't want details of all photos present in a cameraroll. But i want exif information of randomly selected photo by me inside cameraroll.

Comment: the link shows how to get exif data from an alasset. i don't get it.. you wrote that you can get alassets.

Comment: is the question how to get an alasset?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Assume i selected ABC.jpeg from cameraroll. I want to display the exif details of only ABC.jpeg. Not exif details of other photos present in cameraroll.

Comment: when you select ABC you have the corresponding asset as well ... show me how you do it :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan i added the piece of code above, which is giving details of allphotos present in cameraroll

Comment: yes.. and your question is?

Comment: where do you get ABC.jpg

Comment: @Daij-Djan i added my complete code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here is the code how to get the asset of a media picker with the image picker:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
   UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
   self.imageView.image = image;

   NSLog(@"media image info: %@", info);

    //use assetLib 
    NSURL *imageURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    if(imageURL) {
        [self getPictureInfoFromAssetURL:imageURL
                                 success:^(NSDictionary*)alInfo {
                                           NSLog(@"asset lib image info: %@", alInfo);
                                 } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                           NSLog(@"error reading asset lib image info: %@", error);
                                 }];
    }

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)getPictureInfoFromAssetURL:(NSURL *)url
                           success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *alInfo))success
                           failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:url
                   resultBlock: ^(ALAsset *myasset) {
                       ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
                       if(success {
                            success([rep metadata]);
                   }
                  failureBlock: ^(NSError *err) {
                      if (failure) {
                          failure(err);
                      }
                  }];
}
```

Comment: important is `NSURL *imageURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];`

Comment: and `[assetslibrary assetForURL:url ...`

Comment: in ios 9, this is deprecated though.